# Структура базы данных для простой CRM

Tags: база-данных, php, sql, mysql

Сразу оговорюсь, что я еще совсем начинающий, поэтому просьба не обижать.
Есть задача - написать простейшую CRM-систему, с функциями добавления, удаление, сортировки задач и различными несложными фичами. В системе будет 3 уровня (задачи, подзадачи и подподзадачи). Собственно, вопрос вот в чем - как мне организовать структуру базы данных - создавать для каждого уровня отдельную таблицу, связанную с остальными?

Comment: CRM - это система взаимоотношения с клиентами, там сущности: клиенты, заказы, оплаты, контакты, задачи по клиентам или заказам. Если просто задачи, то это система управления задачами или проектами (ToDo, Task Manager, Project Manager, Collaboration Tool)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
users - id, login, (name, password)
tasks - id, parent_id, description, status, (name, time, deadline, date_created) 
task_user - user_id, task_id
```

В скобках - необязательные поля.

Comment: Спасибо. Такая структура предполагает требуемый уровень вложенности? Что-то не могу разобраться...

Comment: какой угодно. parent_id=0 для задачи, parent_id = ЧИСЛО - для подзадачи. ЧИСЛО соответствует id родительской задачи

Comment: Такой еще вопрос появился - как в случае с такой структурой выводить все задачи КОНКРЕТНОГО пользователя, если последнего я идентифицирую по session_id()?

Comment: добавить в таблицу юзеров колонку session_id, в которую записывать этот самый id сессии при каждом логине. 

Весь запрос:

    select t.description from users u left join task_user tu on u.id=tu.user_id left join tasks t on tu.task_id=t.id where u.sess_id=$session_id

Правда куда проще при каждом логине вытаскивать id юзера из таблицы, тогда обращение к ней в запросе исчезнет совсем:

    select t.description from task_user tu left join tasks t on tu.task_id=t.id where tu.user_id=$id

Answer (score 7):

Настораживает наличие подподзадач. Если они так нужны, то их можно реализовать как подзадачи подзадач, то есть обойтись двумя сущностями - задачами и подзадачами. А точнее и вовсе одной - задачами, у которых есть внешний ключ на родительскую задачу. В таком случае все задачи могут быть сохранены в одной таблице, но задачи (именно задачи, а не подзадачи и под-под...подзадачи) будут отличаться тем, что у них не будет родительской задачи Тем самым вы реализуете в общем-то любой уровень вложенности, и отпадет необходимость создавать для каждого уровня свою таблицу

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Не могли бы вы примерно показать как это будет выглядеть? Немного сложно понять как с помощью одной сущности будет реализован любой уровень вложенности.

Comment: у вас может быть таблица примерно такого вида: 

    IdTask,
    IdMasterTask
    ....
    какие-то другие поля

любой уровень вложенности в таком случае достигается с помощью того, что у конкретной задачи IdMasterTask может ссылаться на IdTask другой задачи, а у той в свою очередь - на IDTask следующей, и так сколько угодно до самой верхней, корневой задачи, у которой IdMasterTask будет отсутствовать. кустати, то же самое вам предлагает @knes

Comment: @DreamChild, огромное спасибо за разъяснения, буду пробовать!

Comment: огромное пожалуйста)